# C# rejects column names containing '(' and/or ')' that exist happily in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

The output from C# in VS2019 is as follows

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
> Invalid column name 'Sequence No_(Forward)'.
> Invalid column name 'Sequence No_(Backward)'.
> Invalid column name 'Fixed Scrap Qty_(Accum_)'.
> Invalid column name 'Scrap Factor _(Accumulated)'.

The SQL is

```
SELECT 
    [Sequence No_(Forward)], [Sequence No_(Backward)],
    [Fixed Scrap Qty_(Accum_)], [Scrap Factor _(Accumulated)]  
FROM 
    [AMSNeve2018CU23_Live].[dbo].[AMS Neve LIVE$Routing Line] 
WHERE 
    [Routing No_] = 'SMN812-652';
```

The same query works in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: The same query working in SQL Server Management Studio]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string CString;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CString = "server=NAVSERVER\\NAV;" +
                            "UID=sa;" +
                            "database=AMSNeve2018CU23_Live; " +
                            "connection timeout=30";

            string sql = "SELECT [Sequence No_(Forward)] ";
            sql += "FROM[AMSNeve2018CU23_Live].[dbo].";
            sql += [AMS Neve LIVE$Routing Line] ";
            sql += "WHERE[Routing No_] = 'SMN812-652';";
            FailMiserablyOnRead(sql);
        }
        public static void FailMiserablyOnRead(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //NavRoutingLine Line = new NavRoutingLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your `c#` code?

Comment: Could you add to your question the C# code that is executing this query (and leads to this exception)? Possibly something can be changed there - but we need to see it first

Comment: it seems that in your SSMS query there's a space between `NO_` and `(`  that is missing in the first query you are showing `Sequence No_(Forward)`

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not use 3 part names for database objects. You (or more likely someone else) will find it difficult to migrate your code to different environments (since a migration often involves the use of a different database name). Let the connection determine the database to use for your table references. And NO ONE should be using the sa login for anything but emergencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for a valid column name in SQL Server are different from those in C#. The solution is to rename your SQL columns so they are acceptable to C#.

In your code, replace this:

```
string sql = "SELECT [Sequence No_(Forward)] ";
            sql += "FROM[AMSNeve2018CU23_Live].[dbo].";
            sql += [AMS Neve LIVE$Routing Line] ";
            sql += "WHERE[Routing No_] = 'SMN812-652';";
```

with this:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT     [Sequence No_ (Forward)] As Sequence_No_Forward
    FROM       [AMSNeve2018CU23_Live].[dbo].[AMS Neve LIVE$Routing Line] 
    WHERE      [Routing No_] = 'SMN812-652';
";
```

and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the database is the Microsoft NAV database, and changing is NOT an option.Would c++ and ODBC hit the same snag?

Comment: I don't mean change the column names in the table, I mean change the column names in the query as I suggested in the code I provided. Sorry for the confusion. If that is not an option, please show us your C# code and maybe there's another way round the issue.

Comment: The column name is rejected in the same way unfortunately.

Comment: C++ and ODBC gives exactly the same result.  The mind boggles at those who designed a database that only they can access.  Well done Microsoft! Another fine mess you've got me into.

Comment: @GodfreySmall I would blame whoever came up with those column names, not Microsoft. The problem is with the c# code, not the SQL. In order to help further, we would need to see the actual code which is generating the error.

Comment: I have stripped the code down to something I can post here (except the password) ;-) but have not found a way to post it.  Help!

Comment: Does it say "Share Edit Follow Flag" under your original question? Click "Edit".

Comment: Invalid column name 'Sequence No_(Forward)'. - just the same.

Comment: D'oh! The column name is incorrect. It should be "Sequence No_ (Forward)" not "Sequence No_(Forward)". I updated my reply above. Please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a stored procedure in the database.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procMyProcedure_GET
   @RoutingNum NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT [Sequence No_ (Forward)], 
      [Sequence No_ (Backward)],
      [Fixed Scrap Qty_ (Accum_)], 
      [Scrap Factor _ (Accumulated)]  
   FROM [AMSNeve2018CU23_Live].[dbo].[AMS Neve LIVE$Routing Line] 
   WHERE [Routing No_] = @RoutingNum;
END
```

And then call this from your C# code.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procMyProcedure_GET", con))
{
   con.Open();

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoutingNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "SMN812-652";

   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         //NavRoutingLine Line = new NavRoutingLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Notice how I changed the command type on the sqlcommand object and how I passed in the parameter defined in the stored procedure.

Edit: I also noticed that you are missing the space after the underscores in your column names.

Comment: That wouldn't work either. The column names are incorrect.

Comment: I thought you said it worked in sql management studio?  If it works there then just put that into your stored procedure.

Comment: I see that your missing a space after the underscores in your column names

Answer (score 0):

Mea Culpa. The cause of this whole issue is the space missing before the '('.  Can I thank all those who contributed, and apologize for wasting their time.

Comment: In that case, please feel free to flag my answer as "accepted".